# Angular NgRepeat Nested Json Data

Tags: json, angular, nested, angularjs-ng-repeat

I need to use ng-repeat to read this json file. It is a nested json file. I need to show a list of articles with their source name, the description and URL code is below:

```
    {

    "status": "ok",
    "totalResults": 20,
    "articles": [
        {
            "source": {
                "id": "the-washington-post",
                "name": "The Washington Post"
            },
            "author": null,
            "title": "White House expresses confidence on Kavanaugh confirmation, even as key senators remain unannounced",
            "description": "“As of now, I don’t really know, and I don’t know if anyone else does,” the Senate Judiciary Committee chairman said.",
            "url": "https://www.washingtonpost.com/politics/kavanaugh-vote-hours-before-a-key-test-grassley-says-he-doesnt-know-how-it-will-go/2018/10/05/a71d92ba-c886-11e8-b1ed-1d2d65b86d0c_story.html",
            "urlToImage": "https://www.washingtonpost.com/resizer/GAc4DRZ9o0B5kqDbhd80-2j5b9U=/1484x0/arc-anglerfish-washpost-prod-washpost.s3.amazonaws.com/public/42Q37CWIREI6RMPNDUWWLODNBQ.jpg",
            "publishedAt": "2018-10-05T13:18:45Z",
            "content": "The White House expressed confidence Friday morning that Judge Brett M. Kavanaugh will be confirmed to the Supreme Court, even though several key senators have yet to announce how they will vote in today’s crucial procedural motion. “We are confident Judge Ka… [+6945 chars]"
        },
        {
            "source": {
                "id": null,
                "name": "Bbc.com"
            },
            "author": "https://www.facebook.com/bbcnews",
            "title": "S-400: India missile defence purchase in US-Russia crosshairs",
            "description": "India's purchase of the Russian-made S-400 air defence system runs the risk of US sanctions. So why buy it?",
            "url": "https://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-india-45757556",
            "urlToImage": "https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/1024/branded_news/9198/production/_103727273_c277ce01-cf10-4984-b5b0-92322020a50f.jpg",
            "publishedAt": "2018-10-05T12:57:36Z",
            "content": "Image copyright Getty Images Image caption Russian President Vladimir Putin (left) and Indian PM Narendra Modi signed the deal in Delhi on Friday India has signed a deal with Russia to acquire the S-400 air defence missile system, despite the possibility such… [+6864 chars]"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is my Controller

```
$scope.showNews = function(){
    MainDash.getNews().then(function(data){
        $scope.newsData = data.articles;
    })
}
```

Here is my Service

```
     factory.getNews = function(){
    return $http.get('news.json');
}
```

Comment: Are you using Angular or AngularJs?

Comment: what have you tried in view(in html)?

Comment: <tbody ng-repeat="n in newsData">
          <tr>
            <th scope="row"></th>
            <td>{{n.title}}</td>
            <td><a href="{{n.url}}" target="_blank"><i class="fas fa-newspaper"></i></a></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>

Comment: @Jmostaind55 `{{n.source.name}}` you can access the source name like this, if the source comes as a json object!

Comment: @Ravikumar I have tried that but it is blank. It does not show the data from the json file

Comment: @Jmostaind55 Blank means, u mean even `{{n.title}}` coming as blank?

Comment: pls `console.log($scope.newsData)` and make sure the json is returned by the callback!

Comment: Checked that and the data was undefined. I changed $scope.newsData = data.articles; to $scope.newsData = data; and it is now showing in console. Still not showing in my view

Comment: Figured this out. Changed $scope.newsData = response.data.articles;